# How to remove a file and avoid introducing a race condition?

Tags: c++11, race-condition

I try to remove a file and recreate it if it is corrupted. I used `remove()` and `unlink()`, but both might lead to ***race conditions***. (I found it while I run *static analysis* from Parasoft.)

Does anybody know an alternative?

Comment: Please describe what `static analyzes` is, what *race condition* you are referring to and how `remove()` and `unlink()` contribute to it. (Far as I remember, `remove()` is generic while `unlink()` is *IXy.)

Comment: Hello, @greybeard. I used Parasoft in order to find my project weaknesses, running Parasoft it's so called static analysis. But it warned me that unlink() and remove() can lead to race conditions. This was strange because, according to the unlink() documentation, it is thread safe. Since then I contacted Parasoft team and they confirmed that unlink() can be used in applications that contain threads, but remove() not.